What is the file path to the USB/Windows accessible folder that screenshots are saved to in iOS?
If you take a screenshot in iOS by pressing volume up and power at same time, it saves this in a publicly accessible way, by just connecting a USB cord to Windows. One can navigate to iPhone > Internal Storage > 202403_ > IMG_0001.PNG, for example.
How does this path work? I am programming in .NET and would like to be able to save files to this same location from inside my app so I can easily check them from Windows.
In .NET we have for example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=net-8.0

But I can find no explanation for what the path to this USB accessible folder is or how to get it and save files to it.
Is this possible? Any help?
There should be equivalent .NET methods for any iOS code so any iOS or .NET solution is welcome. Thanks.
